# Capture Request Payload in Javascript

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools, qunit

The web appliation I am testing is making http calls out.  I'm trying to set up a Qunit test to validate those calls.  I need to be able to validate the data that is in the Request Payload of HTTP POST calls.  I can already capture the call iteself but I don't have access to the Request Payload of that call.

Here's what I have so far:

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype._originalOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
    if(url.match(/get/)) {
        QUnit.asyncTest("Validate URL", function( assert ) {
            assert.equal( url.match(my_regex)[0] , expected_url, "Matches");
            // assert.equal( /*Validate Request Payload*/);
            start();
        });
    }
    this._originalOpen(method, url, async, user, password);
}
```

Is there any way to capture the request payload of the call in Javascript?

Comment: While I applaud your efforts to do this yourself, why not use a tool like [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server) or [Mockjax](https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax)?

Comment: I don't actually own the application that I'm testing.  Can I use those tools in my test without modifying the original application?

Comment: Yep. You set everything up in your test file. The Mockjax tool is only for jQuery ajax calls, but Sinon will work with any codebase as it mocks out the core `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Comment: Maybe Pretender is a kind of a library you are searching for. You can easy analyze/verify the content of a request object. take a look of examples https://github.com/trek/pretender

Answer (score 1):

You need to clone the send() method just like you did open, then inspect the arguments:

```
var clone = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
  // console.log(arguments);
  // Continue the send
  clone.apply(this, arguments);
};
```